# Neo4j Enterprise VM Version 3.5 Database Transfer

Tags: neo4j

I upload Neo4j Enterprise VM Version 3.5 to my Azure account. So right now I am using Neo4j in the Azure. 
I created before my database in the local desktop edition and I want to transfer it to Remote one (Neo4j Enterprise VM Version 3.5)  which is in Azure .

However I couldnt find a way to do it. There is no option in Neo4j Enterprise VM Version 3.5 to put my graph.db zip file.

Someone can help to how transfer my local database to remote one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documented way to transfer a neo4j DB is to use:

- The `neo4j-admin dump` command on the originating machine to create a dump file.
- The `neo4j-admin load` command on the destination machine to fill a fresh DB from that dump file.

Refer to [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/) for more details.